# javaFX задать слушатель события

Tags: javafx

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать слушатель событий который срабатывал при зажатой ЛевойКнопкиМыши + клике на ПКМ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слушатель просто получает объект MouseEvent и вы в коде должны его обрабатывать. Какого-то специального слушателя для вашей ситуации нет.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: На SO не нужно благодарить. Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вопрос может и не самый лучший и интересный, но напишите пример кода. Вдруг кому пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ввести переменные, которые будут отвечать за уже нажатую клавишу - левую/правую и в обработчике, во время нажатия мыши проверять не нажата ли противоположная клавиша.
На пример таким образом:

```
isLeftClicked = false;
isRightClicked = false;

void listenerLeft(e) { 
  isLeftClicked = true;
  if (isRightClicked && click) // нажаты обе 
}

void listenerRight(e) { 
  isRightClicked = true;
  if (isLeftClicked && click) // нажаты обе 
}
```